# How to use hashcat to crack a password made with openssl-passwd?

Tags: passwords, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I want use hashcat or John the Ripper to crack the hash of a password.
I know the password was created using the following command:

```
openssl passwd -crypt -salt tl ********
```

The asterisks, of course, are placeholders for the actual password. I know for sure that the password has 8 characters, and that the salt is `tl`. How exactly can I use hashcat or John the Ripper to crack the password hash?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at answering the question yourself yet?

Comment: I tried to do a decrypt with hashcat but i don't know how pass a dictionary with a salt to try to decrypt. Could you help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add those steps that you have tried. The more you add, the easier it is for us to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[openssl passwd](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/openssl-passwd.html) creates a traditional DES crypt hash:

```
-crypt
    Use the crypt algorithm (default).
```

[Hashcat](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) mode 1500 will process that type of hash:

[image: Hashcat generic hash types table]

You don't need to provide the salt, it's part of the encoded hash string, and hashcat will automatically parse it when using hash mode 1500.

Comment: If your hash is in the file `hashfile`, then
`hashcat64.bin -m 1500 -a 3 hashfile` should do it and it shouldn't take too long on modern hardware.

Comment: From manpage of `openssl 3.0.5`: **The -crypt option was removed in OpenSSL 3.0.**